# C Pointer Error

Tags: c, file, pointers, struct

The program below is supposed to read a `txt` file and put the data in a struct. But it gives an pointer error. It gives an error in `strcpy()` about pointers. I'm new in C. Whats wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    struct citydata {
        char city[20];
        int temp;
    };

    struct citydata values[15];

    struct citydata Avg;
    struct citydata high;
    struct citydata low;

    FILE* inp;
    int reccount = 0;
    int x = 0;
    char s;
    int n;

    inp = fopen("mydata.txt", "r");
    if (!inp) {
        printf("Unable ot open file\n");
    }
    while (fscanf(inp, "%s %d", s, &n) != EOF) {
        strcpy(values[x].city, s);
        values[x].temp = n;
        x++;
    }

    fclose(inp);
}
```

Comment: `s` has the wrong type, try `char s[20]` and `fscanf(inp, "%19s %d", s, n) ... `

Comment: Please format code code correctly

Comment: ...and `fclose(inp);` if `fopen` has failed is a bad idea.

Comment: @MichaelWalz It is his style of code formatting. You can not say that it is incorrect.:)

Comment: @VladfromMoscow the formatting style may be (more or less) consistent but it's absolutlely unusual and strange

Comment: how much storage is 'char s' and how much storage is city? The %s reads in how many characters?

Comment: @MichaelWalz: I've done this for OP, using [this site](http://format.krzaq.cc/). Tony: Please do that yourself next time.

Comment: @IharobAlAsimi Ive done that but it still gives an error

Comment: `if (!inp) {
        printf("Unable ot open file\n");
    }` - But the code carries on. Why?

Answer (score 3):

#### Don't ignore compiler warnings.

When if you compile this code (say, with gcc), you get the following warnings:

```
test.c:27:24: warning: format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 3 has type ‘int’ [-Wformat=]
     while (fscanf(inp, "%s %d", s, &n) != EOF) {
                        ^
test.c:28:32: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘strcpy’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
         strcpy(values[x].city, s);
                                ^
In file included from test.c:2:0:
/usr/include/string.h:125:14: note: expected ‘const char * restrict’ but argument is of type ‘char’
 extern char *strcpy (char *__restrict __dest, const char *__restrict __src)
```

so, as comments suggest, you can't scan directly into the struct; you can only scan into simpler types the C standard libraries recognizes: integer, floating-point numbers, `char *` strings etc. Similarly, you can't perform a string copy from your structs, which are not strings.

C is a strongly-typed language with very few allowed implicit conversions. In some cases, you are able to pass integers instead of floats or vice-versa, but nothing "magically converts" into a string, or is "magically parsed" from a string.

#### ... and there are other issues:

- Note @EdHeal 's comment: If your `fopen()` fails, you mustn't continue running the rest of the code. Either you should `exit(EXIT_FAILURE);` or wrap the rest of the code in `main()` within an `else()` block.
- You should printf error messages to the standard error stream, so instead of `printf("error message here")` it should `fprintf(stderr,"error message here")`. Also, the standard C library places an error code you can get as the `errno` variable, or you can have an error message printed to the standard error stream with the `perror()` function. There are a few other related related functions (like `strerror()`, `err() etc.) which I will not get into here.

Answer (score -3):

make some mistakes with pointers=)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


typedef struct citydata
{
    char       *city;
    int        temp;
}              citydata;

int main()
{
   char *s;
   citydata *values;

   values = (citydata*)malloc(sizeof(citydata) * 16);
   FILE * inp;
   int reccount = 0;
   int x = 0;
   int n;
   inp = fopen("mydata.txt", "r");
   if(!inp)
      printf("Unable ot open file\n");
   while (fscanf(inp,"%s %d",s, &n) != EOF)
   {
      values[x].city = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * 20);
      strcpy(values[x].city, s);
      values[x].temp = n;
      x++;
   }
   fclose(inp);
}
```

Comment: `char *s; ...while (fscanf(inp,"%s %d",s, &n) != EOF)`  --> `s` has not yet been assigned value before it use.

Comment: Why did you remove the buffer for the member `city`?